# What is this Nokia networking device?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, hdmi

It has an ethernet cable from my modem.  It also has a very thin wire and what looks like an HDMI cable stuck in it.  The modem has an ethernet WAN cable connecting it to the wall WAN socket.

All this stuff is next to the TV and my roommate mentioned they have the box to record shows.

The problem is, the WiFi my room in the basement, opposite corner from the TV room mentioned above gets no signal when I am on Ubuntu (tried everything under the sun on askubuntu.com and my ASUS wifi adapter which did work just died).

We have two boosters.

Anyways, the main question is, what the heck is this Nokia device?

Ideally, I want to strip down what is connected to the modem as much as possible and move the modem into another room closer to my room then position the boosters so it shoots the signal down the stairs and into my room.

[image: nokia1]

[image: nokia2]

Comment: Please edit your question: You need to post the exact make and model of these devices if you expect anyone to be able to help you. The pic shows the bottom of the device, but the details are so blurry it is impossible to make anything out.

Comment: I think I could make out the model number - it's BVMDC00CRA and searching tells me is a "ONT" - it's the box your ISP gives you when you have fast fiber.  That's your modem, but it doesn't do Wifi, so I would guess that the Telus box is doing the Wifi (and functioning as your wired router too).  Are you sure the Nokia's Ethernet cord is plugged into the wall and not the Telus box?

Comment: That said, a quick search for “Nokia Modem” online shows that _might_ be a Nokia optical modem. Possibly “Nokia 7368 ISAM Ont G-240g-a Gigabit Optical Modem.” Meaning, that device is your ISP’s modem that provides internet service to your place. The wire on the left is the actual connection to the ISP and the Ethernet on the right is your network connection.

Comment: Oh, its definately an ONT or ONR . I couldn't make out the model number but I identified the optical cable almost all consumer modems use

Comment: And now that we know what this thing is, ONT/ONR stands for Optical Network Terminal (ONT) or Optical Network Router (ONR). And PON stands for 
Passive Optical Networking.

Comment: Unrelated - consider whether you can run some fixed ethernet cable from the Router down to your basement - getting wireless signals through floors is generally harder than through walls.  And wired is always faster than wireless.

Comment: @Criggie, the head tenant does not want a wire going down the stairs.  But I'll ask if I can staple it along the wall or somehow get it out of the way.

Comment: @mLstudent33 That might be a good question for DIY.SE or perhaps maybe networking.SE "How to run a hidden ethernet cable so that it does no damage and can be removed later?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TLDR: Its a Its probably ONT or ONR, essentially a modem (ONT) or modem router (ONR) for fibre based internet. Its what I *think* you are or were getting internet off of.

It *shouldn't* be connected to your modem. It should be connected to a *router*. If you have two modems, both connected to your internet, there's going to to be issues if they're plugged into each other.

Thanks to the excellent sluthing by Giacomo1968 and LawrenceC - its apparently a NOKIA 7368.

The connection to the left of your photo, with the thin yellow cable is a fibre optic connection, typically a GPON interface using a APC/SPC connector. (and I see a laser/do not look at light with remaining eye warning - which confirms this). These things are fairly typical for gigabit/fibre internet connections.

Fundamentally - if you don't know what this is *leave it alone*. You're probably better off tracing and labelling the cables you have and understanding your network rather than disconnecting random things and scream testing

I found [the manual for this online](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1836790/Nokia-7368-Isam-Ont-E-240g-B.html?page=1#manual) after someone found the model

[image]

The little covered bit with the laser logo is a fibre optic connection with a similar laser warning -  . The ntwrk light should be on *solidly* and the optical cable is a bit fragile. If its not lit - well firstly make sure you have fibre optic network. IIRC the ISP tends to 'activate' a port on the wall end, so you can't swap that, and the only potential issue is a broken fibre optic cable.

[image: ![enter image description here]

You can probably check the LEDs to troubleshoot as per this table. The NTWK light SHOULD be solid (more typically its called PON) and the fail light shouldn't be red. It does look that everything is ok and its connected to the internet.

Comment: Check out [this eBay listing](https://www.ebay.com/itm/303700995431); a lot closer in form factor to the original poster’s picture.

Comment: Oh *happy annoyed swearing*. Its probably the same model as theirs but the LIGHTS ARE NON STANDARD. WHYYYYYYYYY?

Comment: How are the lights non-standard?

Comment: EVERY single ONT/ONR I've seen called them PON. This says NTWK. I've NEVER seen a MGMT light. That said I found a manual on one of em dodgy russian sites so... its all good

Comment: Additional point - the ONT is generally owned and provided/managed by the fibre company for consistency, whereas the router is owned by the end user.   The router might be managed by the ISP/RSP or the end user.   In my country, there can be up to four RSPs providing service on a single ONT, one per port.